# problem starting nginx / which '}' is unexpected?

Tags: django, nginx

It is my first time trying to launch django-website through VPS. I am trying to follow this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn) but encountered problem launching `nginx`.

Then I am doing `sudo service nginx start` command I get following error:

"*Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*"

So after this error I checked `journalctl -xe` and found out that error was encountered while starting `nginx.service`:

*"nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/skaiciuokle_web"*

and

"*nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed*"

So naturally I checked `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/skaiciuokle_web` file for it content with intention to remove that cursed unexpected `}`, but this is that I found:

```
server {
       server_name 141.136.44.187;
       access_log off;
       location /static/ {
                alias /opt/myenv/static/:
                }

      location / {
               proxy_pass http:/127.0.0.1:8001;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Host $server_name;
               proxy_set header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
               add_header P3P 'CP="All DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
               }
     }
```

To my understanding there is no additional, not needed "}"...

So which one `}` is unexpected and should be removed? Or error means something different and problem is not here?

Comment: Your alias directive ends with :

Comment: fix proxy_pass also `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;` you missed a slash